# Filtering array so it would remove all undefined objects

Tags: arrays, angular, object, lodash

I need to filter an array so it would remove undefined objects from it.

[image]

I tried with lodash _.filter but didn't succeed (returned completely empty array)

```
_.filter(myArray, _.isEmpty)
```

I'm using Angular 6 so anything with typescript or lodash would be perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easier way:

```
_.filter(myArray, Boolean)
```

This rids the array of nulls, 0's and undefined's.

Comment: Thanks a lot, since this is the cleanest way I will accept this answer once I can.

Answer (score 2):

Using Javascript also feasible. it supports null,undefined, 0, empty.

```
newArray = myArray.filter(item=> item);
```

Answer (score 1):

The more simple way

```
_.filter(myArray, function(o) { return o !== undefined });
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a library; [the Javascript array type has a `filter` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
var filteredArray = myArray.filter(item => item !== undefined);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var newArray = array.filter(arrayItem => arrayItem)
```

It will Filtering array so it would remove all undefined objects and assign to new variable called newArray

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/21387784)

Answer (score 1):

In `filter` function of **lodash** if the callback (you passed as argument) return truthy value that element considered to be retained in resultant array otherwise (in case return falsy) it will not retain that element. Your `isEmpty` return `true` if it is Empty and thus the result retains those values (`null`, `undefined`, `0`, ...). So you can either use

`_.filter(myArray, _.negate(_.IsEmpty))` or `_.filter(myArray, v => !_.IsEmpty(v))`

In the way you are trying

Or, you can directly use `_.filter(myArray)` but in this case it will not remove empty object or empty array as same like `_.filter(myArray, Boolean)`, passing `Boolean` is not necessery in case of using `lodash`

in case you don't want to negate and want a simpler solution for removing all the empty element, then you can use

`_.reject(myArray, _.isEmpty)`